# How to store file path in database stored in file system

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I want to create a separate notes file for each user.
The notes files are kept in a network file system(or the server).

Suppose I have a table employee_info

**empid**     **empname**    **pathtofile**

50        John   \\[filepathfromnetworkfilesystem]\50.txt

51        Max  \\[filepathfromnNFS]\51.txt

Which datatype will the 'pathtofile' column be?
I checked BLOB and CLOB, but they store binary, so not sure those are appropriate datatypes here.

And any sample code, how can I access this column from java code to retrieve the contents of the file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the db will store whatever you tell it.  The real question is what code /language you will then use this in. I'd follow that.

Comment: thats good to know....so you mean I can make the column 'pathtofile' as a LONGTEXT and store the path there?

I basically want to use java to fetch the path and then go to the path and retrieve the text elements from the text file.

Comment: No such thing in Oracle DB. But you can do a varchar2(4000)

Comment: OK, I will try to use varchar2 and will see if it works. Thank for the help.

But still I am looking for a sample code in Java.

Comment: I have put the tags as Java.